# How to securely store a user's passwords in open source software?

Tags: encryption

I'm writing a piece of open-source client software that can connect to web services on behalf of a user. The user enters his username and password, and the software connects using those credentials.

For convenience purposes, I have an option for the software to save the user's credentials so that they don't need to be entered again in the future.

However, since this is open-source, I'm not sure how I can store the credentials in a reasonably secure way. It strikes me that any method I use to encrypt the password could easily be reversed and used to decrypt the password. I realize that perfect security is impossible, but is there a better practice than using ROT13 like I'm currently doing?

Comment: Depending on your platform, there might be a system API to store and retrieve credentials in a relatively secure way.

Comment: If you are writing in a language that has a pseudo random generator, you can also do something like that : srand([random_number_generated_at_compile_time]); passwd += rand() + rand();. That's not so secure, but it's better than nothing I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty good [treatment of saved passwords](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/PlainTextPasswords) in an open-source client by the Pidgin developers; the same reasoning would apply to a web service client.

Executive summary:

- If the app saves passwords itself, leave them in plain text and set the file permissions to be readable only by the user.  (This makes it obvious that the settings file is sensitive!)
- Provide the option to integrate with a platform keyring API such as [the Windows Data Protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) or a keyring application like [KeePass](http://keepass.info/index.html).